# Carrierwave extension whitelist error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am using carrierwave with Rails 5. In my extension white list allowed types are jpg, jpeg and png.

The default error message is:

```
"You are not allowed to upload \"gif\" files, allowed types: jpg, jpeg, png"
```

I don't need customization as message is fine except \"gif\". What I want is:

```
"You are not allowed to upload gif file, allowed types: jpg, jpeg, png"
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: "I don't need customization" - but you do. And unfortunately, customising the message won't be enough.  The source of the word `\"gif\"` is  `extension` variable passed from `check_extension_whitelist!` to I18n, so you will need to override/extend that method: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/ba782cc6328f5a1de1d846950a25601f88509eff/lib/carrierwave/uploader/extension_whitelist.rb#L38 . Shortly, you need `extension: extension` instead of `extension: new_file.extension.inspect` on line 41

Comment: By customization I meant any other custom message. Anyways Thanks a lot. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering based on solution suggested by @mizurnix. It worked for me.

Overrode the `check_extension_whitelist!` method in avatar uploader(app/uploaders/avatar_uploader.rb) i.e. added below code in avatar_uploader.rb.

```
private

  def check_extension_whitelist! new_file
    extension = new_file.extension.to_s
    if extension_whitelist && !whitelisted_extension?(extension)
      raise CarrierWave::IntegrityError, I18n.translate(:"errors.messages.extension_whitelist_error", extension: extension, allowed_types: Array(extension_whitelist).join(", "))
    end
  end

  def whitelisted_extension? extension
    downcase_extension = extension.downcase
    Array(extension_whitelist).any? { |item| downcase_extension =~ /\A#{item}\z/i }
  end
```

Comment: I am glad you found my suggestion helpful. Could you edit this answer to show where exactly in your app (in initializers probably?) you added this override. Also, I think you can use `extension: extension` instead of `extension: new_file.extension` in your method as you have that variable anyway

Comment: Edited with uploader path and yes extension: extension will also do the job so now using that only.